# How to call custom created phtml file in Cms page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-pages

I am finding a way to call my custom created phtml file in Cms page. The file is located in **Magento_catalog > product > bestseller.phtml**, And the way which I am trying is -

`{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_catalog::product/bestseller.phtml"}}`

`{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" template="Magento_Catalog::product\bestseller.phtml"}}`

But the file is not loading in Cms page. Please help me to do it.

Thanks

Comment: `bestseller.phtml` is your custom phtml?

Comment: Yes its my custom created phtml file...

Answer (score 0):

In first syntax, you did not capitalise the "C" in Magento_catalog .Correct syntax is below

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

in second syntax, you can not use product description block in cms page. Because it required product in registry so you can only use it on product detail page.